# How to end regex match at first occurrence of end word

Tags: ruby, regex

I have:

```
myString = String.new("Test String which should end here here")
```

I want `matchString` to be `"String which should end here"`. I did:

```
matchString = myString[/\String which\b.*here?/,0]
```

The `matchString` is `"String which should end here here"`. The match is going until the end of the second `'here'` word. I have tried adding the non-greedy `?` after `'here'`, but its not working.

How do I stop the match after the first `'here'`?

Comment: `?` when comes before a quantifier it makes it non-greedy. So remove that `?` and add it before `.*`: `.*?`

Comment: `e?` means "zero or one e", `.*?` is the non-greedy `.*`.

Comment: Why `\String` rather than `String`, considering that `"Btring"` matches `\String`. `\S` means "match any character other than a whitespace"?

Comment: Side note: I wonder why this post got downvotes. It is a perfectly legal programming question, the question is expressed in an understandable way, and the OP at least shows his attempts and even explained his approach.

Answer (score 1):

Add a non-greedy `?` to the `.*`:

```
matchString = myString[/\String which\b.*?here?/,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments `.*` is greedy, you need to make it lazy. Use `\A` meaning start of string as well.

```
str = "Test String which should end here here"
str[/\A.*?here/] #=> "Test String which should end here"
```

Do not use camelCase for variables, use snake_case as above.

Comment: OP doesn't want to start match from beginning of string, explicitly.

Comment: @revo yes you are correct. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Is `\A` needed (if the match were to start at the beginning of the string)?

Comment: @Cary I hadn't thought about that but I guess not. If only to add some clarity perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString[/\String which\b.*?here/]
#=> "String which should end here"
```